# ProgressIndicator not animating on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to display progress indicator on screen when  images loading from web. i'm used below code.,

```
Bitmap bitmap ;
    BitmapField imageField ;
    VerticalFieldManager vfm= new VerticalFieldManager();
    ProgressAnimationField spinner =new ProgressAnimationField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner2.png"));                      
    vfm.add(spinner);
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            bitmap =  new UrlToImage(Constants.ICON_URL+"_big.png"+suffix).getImage();                            
            imageField = new BitmapField(bitmap);
            vfm.delete(spinner)
            vfm.add(imagefield);
        }
    }).start();
```

If i execute , it throws illegalStateException. Again i change to ui thead.,

```
    Bitmap bitmap ;                                                                                                           
    BitmapField imageField ;
    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();                                                                
    ProgressAnimationField spinner =new ProgressAnimationField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner2.png"));                           
    vfm.add(spinner);
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            bitmap =  new UrlToImage(Constants.ICON_URL+"_big.png"+suffix).getImage();                                    
            imageField = new BitmapField(bitmap);
            vfm.delete(spinner)
            vfm.add(imagefield);

        }
    });
```

No error display. but the progressanimationfield not animated.
What to change on my code for animate the progressAnimatedField.   Pls give any idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to do both UI and non-UI operations on the UI thread.  So, your `UrlToImage` is holding the UI thread hostage while it is retrieving data from the network, preventing all other UI operations (including re-painting your animated progress indicator).  What about something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap ;                                                                                                           
BitmapField imageField ;
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();                                                                
ProgressAnimationField spinner =new ProgressAnimationField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("spinner2.png"));                           
vfm.add(spinner);
new Thread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        bitmap =  new UrlToImage(Constants.ICON_URL+"_big.png"+suffix).getImage();                                    
        imageField = new BitmapField(bitmap);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
            public void run() {            
                vfm.delete(spinner);
                vfm.add(imagefield);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already marked as answered, but I was thinking you should look at my post about this subject [here](http://dftr.ca/?p=235)

It should make all your application heartbeat problems go away.